# Benchmarking vessel in-port efficiency - t-test, OLS regression?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference

I’m working on a report on length of berth stays for cargo vessels visiting different ports. I would like to be able to benchmark whether vessels in a given fleet (i.e. a customer’s entire fleet of vessels) have shorter/longer berth stays than other vessels calling the same ports.

The length of a berth stay depends on both ship and shore personnel. Hence, when benchmarking in-port efficiency across ports, I need to correct for differences across these ports. My approach has therefore been to derive the average length of the fleet’s berth stay at each port and compare this average to that of all other port calls to the same port (i.e. for all vessels not in my customer’s fleet of vessels). Having done this for each port, I have found the difference in the average port stay between my customer’s fleet and all other vessels. I have then proceeded to weigh each of these differences by the number of fleet port calls to each port in order to arrive at a weighted average difference in berth stay between my customer’s fleet and all other port calls across all the ports in my data sample (I've attached a picture of my equation).

[image: Equation]

However, I would also like to be able to state whether the weighted average difference in port stay is significantly different between my customer’s fleet and all other vessels. I have been thinking of two different ways to do this:

1. Perform a one-sample t-test where I test the null hypothesis that the average fleet berth stay = the average berth stay of all other calls against an alternative hypothesis that these averages are not equal. I would then have a number of observations equal to the number of ports (p). However, this approach would not take into account that the number of observations for each port may be very different, e.g. 100 fleet port calls to Port A and 2 fleet port calls to Port B
2. Run an OLS regression where the dependent variable is the length of a port stay and the independent variables would be port (dummy variable to correct for differences in shore personnel efficiency and port infrastructure) and a dummy variable indicating whether the observation is a fleet port call or another vessel. If the latter independent variable is significant, I guess I could then conclude that there is a significant difference in berth stay (i.e. in-port efficiency) between vessels in my customer’s fleet and all other vessels.

Any input would be highly appreciated! Perhaps my entire approach, both the average difference in berth stay and the above two options, is flawed (for instance, the number of observations for other port calls is not accounted for in the weighted average difference in berth stay). My goal is still to say 1) whether there is a significant difference in berth stay between a given fleet of vessels and all other vessels calling the same ports and 2) what the average difference in berth stay is. I’ve attached an example data set for good measure.

[image: Data]

I hope someone can help me out. Many thanks for your help